# Regular expression to match a substring

Tags: python, regex

I am working on alphanumeric data extraction from strings like

```py
ABCADE12345ZYX
LMNADE12345ZXY
```

I need to extract `ADE12345` from the first string and `ADE12345` from the second string.

I have tried to use the following regular expression:

```
[ABC|LMN]+(\w+)Z.*
```

But this results in `DE12345` for the first case and `DE12345` for the second case.

How can I get expeected matches - `ADE12345` and `ADE12345` - in Python using `re`?

Comment: You are confusing a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this regex:

```py
(?:ABC|LMN)(\w+)Z
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/70PYnG/2/).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ABC                      'ABC'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    LMN                      'LMN'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Z                        'Z'
```

[**Python code**](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEolaukokTBVkHd0cnZ0cXV0MjYxDQqMkIhMS9FwcfXDy4UEanOVVCUmVeiUZSql5aZl5KYk6NRpK5hbwXUWANUqakRU66tGaWuowA0UFPz/38A):

```py
import re
txt = 'ABCADE12345ZYX and LMNADE12345ZXY'
print(re.findall(r'(?:ABC|LMN)(\w+)Z', txt))
# ['ADE12345', 'ADE12345']
```

Comment: Can you take a look at the edit, I need it to handle a couple different cases